# Typing Greek Letters on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, letters

I've just started using MATLAB and one of my assignments requires me to use Greek letters (in particular, α). I tried copying it into the code area, and also tried using the \alpha command, none of which seem to work.

I get the error message: ***"|
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator."***

Could anyone tell me how I can get it to work or perhaps if there's another way to type Greek letters?

Thanks!

Comment: why not just type `alpha` as the var name?

Comment: You may be confusing this with Mathematica.  Though Mathematica can accept symbols as variables, MATLAB cannot.  Please see the duplicate question for more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the greek letter α as a variable name.  For that you should simply type it as `alpha`.  If you want, however, you can use it in a plot and other UI elements.

For example you might want to set the title of the plot to something such as:

```
title('Intensity (\alpha = .2)')
```